# JQuery Validate error messages out of place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, checkbox

I have a form which is being validated using Jquery Validate.The form contains 2 checkboxes with the same name, of which **at least** one has to be selected. To accomplish this, i am using the .validate() on the checkboxes name , along with the rule :required".

While i am able to validate successfully, (i.e error messages pop up when no checkboxes are selected), the error messages are being displayed after the first checkbox, which disrupsts my formatting.

I am currently using errorElement and errorPlacement to make the error messages show up in a pair of span tags after each input element, but it seems to be not applying to the checkboxes.

HTML(Extract) :

```
<form id='BizAddItem' name='BizAddItem' method='post' action='additemprocess.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' novalidate='novalidate'>

        //More input elements above

        <div class='BizAddItemDetails'>
            <label for='BizFulfilment'>Order Fulfilment:</label>
            <input type='checkbox' id='BizFulfilment' name='BizFulfilment[]'>Delivery &nbsp
            <input type='checkbox' id='BizFulfilment' name='BizFulfilment[]'>In-Store Pickup
            <span></span>
        </div>
        //More input elements below

</form>
```

jQuery code (Extract):

```
$('#BizAddItem').validate({

    errorElement:"span",
    errorPlacement:function(error,element){

        error.insertAfter(element);

    },

    rules:{

        //More items above

        'BizFulfilment[]':{

            required:true
        },

    },

    messages:{

        //More items above

        'BizFulfilment[]':{

            required:"Please select at least one option"
        },
    },

        submitHandler:function(form){

        form.submit();

        }

})
```

Any help rendered would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
 errorPlacement:function(error, element)
        {
            if($(element).attr("name")=="BizFulfilment[]")
            {
                $(element).parent().append(error);
            }else
            {
            $(error).insertAfter(element);
            }   
        },
```

Comment: If i understood your code correctly, you check the errors for the checkboxes(BizFuliflment) and then append the error message to the parent(the containing div in this case)? If so why doesn't insertAfter work for the checkboxes?

Comment: insertAfter means after the first checkbox.(Here between the two check boxes).So use  $(element).parent().append(error);